# MQTT is it possible for publisher to define allowed subscribers on topic?

Tags: python, security, mqtt

I have a basic MQTT question: If I have a broker that I can't configure myself but publish or subscribe anonymous, is it possible for the publisher to define the allowed clients on the topic?

E.g. with mosquitto I can define a ACL file but only at the broker site.

If it is not possible, what would be the best way to encrypt the published data with python?

Comment: Could you give some more context? Generally you can encrypt your broker TLS/SSL based. This could be a starting point: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html Are you asking for some kind of a whitelist inside the network?

Comment: well, I want to use an existing mosquitto broker but be independent of the mosquitto admin. There are different other subscribers on the broker. I could surely encrypt the payload of the messages but I wonder if I could as a publisher allow or deny the subscription on "my" topic.

Comment: I guess I understand. End to end encryption (E2E) would be the best way I guess. https://medium.com/@renugopal17.siva/iot-mqtt-payload-encryption-at-the-application-layer-58f8957d4b5f This guy found an interesting solution, maybe this could be a starting point for you. He has written in C, but should be working in python too.

Comment: OK, this is what I had in mind.  I already have a running Python code for payload end to end encryption.I hoped that there would be a more "generic" way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a MQTT publisher has absolutely no knowledge or control over which clients can subscribe to the topic it publishes messages.

MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, one of it's key tenets is to totally decouple the publisher from the subscriber. The may be anything from 0 to n subscribers when a message is published.

The only option of control is as mentioned in the comments by @GDagger is that you  could encrypt the payload so only authorised subscribers could decrypt it. Since MQTT payloads are just a collection of bytes you can send anything you want (with in the 256mb size limit)

On the other hand the broker has complete control, it can use ACLs to decide which clients can publish or subscribe to which topics.